# networkX node colours wrong oder

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, networking

I am trying to use the NetworkX library and I am having troubles getting my nodes to display the correct colour. Below is a simple example where I am using a colormap. From my understanding node 'B' should show up as red, but as you can see in the picture 'C' is red.   Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?  Many thanks.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use("agg")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches

failed_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='failed')
success_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='success')
plt.legend(handles=[success_patch,failed_patch])

G=nx.DiGraph()
nodes = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
G.add_path(nodes)

color_map = ['forestgreen', 'red', 'forestgreen', 'forestgreen']
lpos =  { 'A': (-0.008, 0), 'B': (-0.008, -5), 'C': (-0.008, -10),
          'D': (-0.008, -15)}
pos = { 'A': (0, 0), 'B': (0, -5),'C': (0, -10),'D': (0, -15)}

nx.draw(G,node_size=1000,alpha=0.8,pos=pos,node_color=color_map,
        node_shape='o',font_size=16, with_labels=True)

plt.savefig('diagram.png')
```

[image]

Comment: not sure why your getting that result. your code on my machine produces `Red` for node `B` https://i.imgur.com/rkzZj5v.png, only change i made what `matplotlib.use("TkAgg")`

Comment: I doubt the code you show here produces the graph that is shown, simply be cause there is no *partial* anywhere in the code. Make sure to show the actual output of your code.